# WP connection, lookup in children causes unexpected error when in view

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, lookup-column, connected-web-parts

I have the following scenario:

MainList / ChildrenList {MainList:ID lookup column, ThirdList:ID lookup column}

In the **MainList display item form**:

- WP#1: MainList with columns {ID, Title, Description}
- WP#2: ChildrenList with columns {MainList:ID, ID, Title, Date, ThirdList:ID}, getting filter from MainList

This works fine.

But when I add the ThirdList:Title to the ChildrenList view, MainList display item form throws a unexepected error.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank u.

---

UPDATE w MORE TROUBLESHOOT INFO:

When the ChildrenList is not connected (via filter) to MainList, there´s no error when ThirdList:Title columns is in the WP#2 ChildrenList view.

Comment: What is the error message (from the browser & ULS)?

Comment: Browser: simply unexpected error, showing the correlation ID. No access to ULS, it's a online plan, no logs (only app logs), Phil